# Javascript event loops in parallel

Tags: javascript, event-loop, asynchronous-javascript

I am reading a book on Asynchronous programming in Javascript. So Async is implemented in serial but I read in this book that it is possible to have parallelism by having cooperating event loops in separate threads. I am just curious as to how and why this is done in practice.

Comment: Define `event loops` in your case. The browser event loop logic is single threaded.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have "threads" by itself, but often (web) workers and different tabs are running in distinct threads.

Comment: "How" - that's what you already explained: multiple event loops in separate threads. "Why" - because parallel on multiple cores is faster than serial.

Comment: @Bergi Webworkers is a topic thats been gleaned over in a lot of my reading. Is it the closest thing that javascript has in terms of multithreading?

Comment: @Andy Yes, that and child-processes or clusters on the server side. Though of course the heavy IO work that usually takes most of the processing time runs concurrently in the background anyway, and communicates exactly through the asynchronous event loop.